# Как добавить UIElement на Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf

Нарисовал UIElement в отдельном представлении и хочу добавить её на Canvas в заданную точку. Через DrawingVisual добавить UIElement  нельзя. Через Canvas.SetLeft() и Canvas.SetLeft() тоже не получается. Подскажите как это сделать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы хотите сделать это в коде (зачем??), то так:

```
canvas.Chilren.Add(uiElement);
Canvas.SetLeft(uiElement, x);
Canvas.SetTop(uiElement, y);
```

Убедитесь, что ваш `uiElement` не добавлен уже в другом месте в UI, иначе получите исключение.

Answer (score 1):

Может взять Grid, поместить в него Canvas и нужный элемент, установить для элемента нужные Margin, Alignment и размеры. 
Они просто наложатся друг на друга. 
Canvas будет фоном.

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл причину почему не хотела добавлять.
Дело в том, что я предопределил класс Canvas и методы работы с Visual, а они отбрасывали все мои попытки добавить объекты по другому.
Добавить получилось так:

```
 Canvas.SetLeft(ui,100);
 Canvas.SetTop(ui,100);
 workSpace.Children.Add(ui);
```